# Cannot compile kernel: error, kernel does not support PIC mode

Tags: linux-kernel, kali-linux, kernel-modules, kernel-parameters

I have troubles recompiling my Kernel. Downloading the source package, decompress it and running

```
fakeroot make-kpkg kernel_image
```

leads me to the error

```
               [...]

  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  UPD     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CHK     include/generated/package.h
  UPD     include/generated/package.h
  CC      kernel/bounds.s
kernel/bounds.c:1:0: error: code model kernel does not support PIC mode
```

The issue may be solved by changing the Kernel configuration obtained with `make menuconfig`.

**How to get rid of this error and have successful compilation**

Comment: That PIE has nothing to do with your problem. What exact distribution and package versions are you using? What version of make and gcc? On what architecture?

Comment: `uname -a` gives me `Linux hostname 4.6.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.6.4-1kali1 (2016-07-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux`  and gcc version is `gcc (Debian 6.2.0-9) 6.2.0 20161019`. I have followed [those](http://docs.kali.org/development/recompiling-the-kali-linux-kernel) precise indications .

Answer (score 8):

From [http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.8-rc2/0002-UBUNTU-SAUCE-no-up-disable-pie-when-gcc-has-it-enabl.patch](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v4.8-rc2/0002-UBUNTU-SAUCE-no-up-disable-pie-when-gcc-has-it-enabl.patch)

You might try the following patch:

```
diff --git a/Makefile b/Makefile
index 5c18baa..e342473 100644
--- a/Makefile
+++ b/Makefile
 @@ -612,6 +612,12 @@ endif # $(dot-config)
 # Defaults to vmlinux, but the arch makefile usually adds further targets
 all: vmlinux
 
+# force no-pie for distro compilers that enable pie by default
+KBUILD_CFLAGS += $(call cc-option, -fno-pie)
+KBUILD_CFLAGS += $(call cc-option, -no-pie)
+KBUILD_AFLAGS += $(call cc-option, -fno-pie)
+KBUILD_CPPFLAGS += $(call cc-option, -fno-pie) 
+
 # The arch Makefile can set ARCH_{CPP,A,C}FLAGS to override the default
 # values of the respective KBUILD_* variables
 ARCH_CPPFLAGS :=
```

A couple of related Debian tickets:

- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=835148
- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=841420

And a related GCC report:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77464

Comment: How does one apply this patch? See also my related question about compiling the Intel e1000e driver, which gives the same error: http://askubuntu.com/questions/851721/ubuntu-16-10-intel-e1000e-driver-cannot-be-compiled-because-kernel-does-not-supp

Comment: /usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-27/arch/x86$ cat ~/e1000e-3.3.4/disable-pie.patch | sudo patch -p1
patching file Makefile
patch: **** malformed patch at line 7: all: vmlinux

Comment: For the patch I show above, this is meant to be applied to the Makefile in the linux directory.  For example, after downloading https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.8.15.tar.xz, and expanding the source, change into linux-4.8.15, and there should be a Makefile there.  The patch above is applied to that Makefile, or just manually edit the file (I use sed to apply the change). Another note:  the flags are needed with gcc6 but not with gcc5.

Comment: I use the following for my kernel builds:  https://github.com/rburkholder/vagrant/blob/master/bldkrnlpkg/buildkrnl.sh on debian/stretch